# Automation Testing with Selenium using Safari Browser

Tags: java, selenium, automation

There is a problem when I'm executing selenium test scripts against the safari browser.

- problem is: - I'm testing an application in which the front end is built from Angular. There is a popup modal build using Prime-Ng and it is not opening when I'm running my test scripts with the safari browser. But the safe script worked for both Firefox and Chrome browsers.

This is My code: -

```
@Test(priority = 24)
public void testExitPopUp()throws Exception{
    try {
        gp.linktoExitgdpr.click();
       // gp.linktoExitgdpr.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
        logger.info("Exit Link Is Selected");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        if (gp.exirtPopUpPane.isDisplayed()) {
            logger.info("Pop up Window is Displayed");
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        } else {
            logger.info("Pop up Window is not Displayed");
            captureScreen(driver, "PopUPError");
            Assert.fail();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        logger.info("Missing Elements (Exception)");
        captureScreen(driver, "exceptionmissingelemnts");
        Assert.fail();
    }
}
```

Note: - here all the elements are called from another class.
The following code shows how I fetched those Elements.

**linktoExitgdpr -**
@FindBy(xpath = "/html/body/app-root/app-survey-layout/app-survey/app-survey-gdpr/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/a")
@CacheLookup
public WebElement linktoExitgdpr;

**exirtPopUpPane -**
@FindBy(xpath = "/html/body/app-root/app-survey-layout/app-survey/app-survey-gdpr/div[2]/p-toast/div/p-toastitem/div")
@CacheLookup
public WebElement exirtPopUpPane;

Comment: can you share the error and the code?

Comment: Dear, @Razvan, I have edited the code in the question. Please check.

Comment: not sure if the problem is related to your code. Does the pop-up appear when you do it manually?

Comment: Yes, Razvan. That is the concern here.

Comment: Prime-ng comes from Angular, and java+selenium is not the best tool to automate these type of applications, some time they can get tricky and annoying. Try go in debug mode and stop exactly at the step when the pop-up should come, then try to see if is any error in the console/network, maybe the application has a "boot-protection" feature for Safari. Also, make sure that you have this capability set to safariDriver: javascriptEnabled='true'

Comment: I'll try Razvan and let you know. Thank You

Comment: Np, keep me posted here, I'm really curios because I faced a lot of similar issues in the past

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest PrimeNG 9.0.6. and Angular: 9.1.2 check that the production variable has a true value in the `enviroment.production` variable and the `enableProdMode()` must be called when the project is built for production `ng build --prod` .

`if (environment.production) { enableProdMode(); }`